# A Simple Grails form. I'm at a loss

Tags: forms, grails

I will preface this by saying my background is Graphic Design (been doing JavaScript for a few years).Ok, I've been looking and looking for a simple tutorial on how to create a basic form with a a controller, that sends the form info in the body of an email.

This is what I have in my GSP:

```
<g:form name="batchform"   url="[action:'forminfo', controller:'onboardingform'] />
<label>Application Group or Area</label>
<g:textField name="apparea01" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 1" value='${params.apparea01}' />
<label>Department Name</label>
<g:textField  name="deptname02" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 2" value='${params.deptname02}' />

<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="FormButton" >
<g:form>
```

And the controller is where I get confused:

```
package .com
import util.Environment
import MailTools
import MetricsLogger

class OnboardingformController {
        String apparea01,
    String deptname02

        static constraints = {
        apparea01 blank: false, nullable: false
        deptname02 blank: false, nullable: false
                }

         def index() {
        render (view:'onboardingform.gsp')

             }

         sendMail {
        to 'me@email.com'
        cc params.mail
        subject 'I am the form test in the subjectline'
        body 'i am the body of the form. I should have vars here that display the user input from form fields'

        }

}
```

I do not currently have a DOMAIN set up since there is no DB attached to this site. I just need to shove those Field Inputs into the Email body. I realize this maybe a very basic operation that escapes me (my background is Fine Arts, not Computer Science).

The MailTools is configured already to a default mailbox. The form needs to be send to another email address.
The MetricsLogger captures user info upon landing on the page.

Thanks in advance. This knowledge will open my eyes in my quest to be an Artist / Programmer :)

Comment: seems that you're mixing Controller, Service and Domain conceptions. It's supposed to be 3 separate classes. Also, don't think that you really need `package .com` at this moment (and it cannot start with dot), just put your controller into `controllers` dir (same for `domain` and `service`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came up with this controller in

`grails-app/controllers/test/OnboardingformController.groovy`:

```
package test

class OnboardingformController {

    def index() { 
        render( view: 'onboardingForm.gsp' )
    }

    def formSubmission( String apparea01, String deptname02, String email ) {
        println "Send Mail from $email to me@email.com with apparea01=$apparea01 and deptname02=$deptname02"
        /*
        // Commented out for now so I don't have to set up mail ;-)
        sendMail {
            to 'me@email.com'
            cc params.mail
            subject 'I am the form test in the subjectline'
            body 'i am the body of the form. I should have vars here that display the user input from form fields'
        }
        */
        redirect( action:'index' )
    }
}
```

And this GSP `grails-app/onboardingform/onboardingform.gsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>Onboarding</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:form action="formSubmission">
            <p>
                <label>Application Group or Area</label>
                <g:textField name="apparea01" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 1" value='${params.apparea01}' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Department Name</label>
                <g:textField name="deptname02" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 2" value='${params.deptname02}' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email</label>
                <g:textField name="email" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 3" value='${params.email}' />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="FormButton" >
            </p>
        </g:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which when the form is filled in, should print out the values you entered (to the console) and redirect to the form.  Let me know if anything doesn't make sense :-)

If you need validation (without a domain object), you can use a Command Object.  This changes the controller to:

```
package test

class OnboardingformController {

    def index() { 
        render( view: 'onboardingForm.gsp' )
    }

    def formSubmission( SubmissionCommandObject cmd ) {
        if( !cmd.validate() ) {
            render( view: 'onboardingForm.gsp', model:[ data: cmd ] )
            return
        }
        else {
            println "Send Mail from $cmd.email to me@email.com with apparea01=$cmd.apparea01 and deptname02=$cmd.deptname02"
        }
        redirect( action:'index' )
    }

}

class SubmissionCommandObject {
    String apparea01
    String deptname02
    String email

    static constraints = {
        apparea01 blank: false, nullable: false
        deptname02 blank: false, nullable: false
        email blank: false, email: true
    }
}
```

And the view to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>Onboarding</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:hasErrors bean="${data}">
            <g:renderErrors bean="${data}" as="list" />
        </g:hasErrors>
        <g:form action="formSubmission">
            <fieldset>
                <p class="prop ${hasErrors(bean:data, field:'apparea01', 'errors')}">
                    <label>Application Group or Area</label>
                    <g:textField name="apparea01" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 1" value='${data?.apparea01}' />
                </p>
                <p class="prop ${hasErrors(bean:data, field:'deptname02', 'errors')}">
                    <label>Department Name</label>
                    <g:textField name="deptname02" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 2" value='${data?.deptname02}' />
                </p>
                <p class="prop ${hasErrors(bean:data, field:'email', 'errors')}">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <g:textField name="email" type="text" placeholder="Place Holder Text Field 3" value='${data?.email}' />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="FormButton" >
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </g:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, this could be prettier, but will suffice for this quick example

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to try this out. You rock!

Comment: Tim, Yes I can get the form to write the params to console, so the form is working. Thanks for asking. Now my facing an issue with emailing the form. So, I'm half way there!